# É correto usar códigos PHP na camada view junto com HTML?

Tags: php, html, mvc, estilo-de-codificação, view

Estou começando agora na área e tenho um trabalho da faculdade pra fazer e é necessário usar o padrão MVC, tenho até separado bem as coisas, porém me deparei com o seguinte código num arquivo da minha camada *view*, o nome do arquivo é `novoAtendimento.php` (nome é sugestivo).

No seguinte código, tenho um campo `<select>` em HTML e os `<option>` dele são gerados de acordo com as informações que temos no banco de dados, se adicionarmos 1 valor no banco de dados, esse valor vai aparecer no `<option>` e se removermos do banco, esse valor vai sumir do `<option>`, o código está funcionando certinho, apenas gostaria de saber se é correto fazer isso.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tipoAtendimento">Tipo do Atendimento:</label>
          <?php
          $tipoAt = new TipoAtendimentoController(); 
          $retornoTipoAt = $tipoAt->select(); 
          if(count($retornoTipoAt) > 0)
          {
               echo "<select class=".'selectpicker'." data-size=".'5'." data-live-search=".'true'." data-width=".'100%'.">";
               foreach ($retornoTipoAt as $dados => $value) 
               {    
                    echo "<option data-subtext=".$retornoTipoAt[$dados]->id_GAPtipoatendimento.">".$retornoTipoAt[$dados]->nome_GAPtipoatendimento."</option>"; 
               }
               echo "</select>"; 
          }
          else
          { 
               header("Location: erro.php");
          }
          ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto sempre é um pouco controverso, faz parte daquela área da computação que é uma arte.

É claro que é quase impossível fazer uma página que não tenha algum código, a não ser em algum caso trivial. Então algum código sempre será necessário.

O que considera-se ideal é que tudo seja preenchido pronto do modelo e não precise codificar, mas pragmaticamente fica complicado fazer algo assim, até impossível em alguns casos.

Como criará o HTML adequado para vários itens sem ter um laço? HTML não tem laços, precisa do PHP para isto. Uma solução sem laço seria engessada e longa demais, fora de cogitação em quase todas situações.

Mesmo uma decisão, um cálculo simples, uma formatação pode ser necessária no código. Tudo é possível trazer de um *modelview* pronto, mas quase sempre não é o ideal. Se é algo que deva definir de acordo com a apresentação, faça nela.

Eu acho muito estranho criar um *controller* dentro da *view*, pra mim parece errado, o controlador deveria fornecer o modelo do jeito que a *view* precisa, não o contrário, e aí talvez o controlador esteja errado também. O resto parece razoavelmente adequado.

Algumas pessoas preferirão ter todo o código HTML fora do código PHP e não com um `echo`.

Comment: Concordo, algumas duvidas sobre o padrão podem ser esclarecidas em: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/